# Submit form with a multidimensional array from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i have a big form with lot of inputs.
Also i have a javascript multidimensional array. It's an array of custom objects, that they are adding and removing as a shopping cart .
The array is defined as a local JS variable.
When i submit the form, i need to pass the array too, and i don't know how to do it.
Here I leave an example, it's illustrative only , as my form and my classes are much more complex .

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var itemList = [];

var CustomClass = function (id, description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
          };

function addItem(id, description)
{
    var item = new CustomClass( id,description);

    itemList.push(item);
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="formSave.php">

<input type="text" name="someInput1">
<input type="text" name="someInput2">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were set on using a form to submit your data, id make a hidden text input and use `JSON.stringify(data)` in your js and decode it on server with `json_decode` server side.

```
<input id = 'jsValueHolder' style = 'display:none'>
<script>
    function loadJSDataBeforeSend(dataToSend){
         document.getElementById("jsValueHolder").value = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    }
    loadJSDataBeforeSend(itemList);
</script>
```

And on server side:

```
<?php
   /* other code */
   $jsonDataString = ... // get your data from the input
   $dataObject = json_decode($jsonDataString);
   $dataKeyValueArray = json_decode($jsonDataString, true);
?>
```

Note how adding true to the json_decode function returns a key value array rather than a php object.